# Where are these dependencies coming from?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am having an issue determining where these spring dependencies are coming from in my project

> **org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile [INFO]
>   |  +-
>   org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +-
>   org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile**

as these are not defined in my pom.xml - this is my dependency tree snippet below

```
 [INFO] |  +- com.ryantenney.metrics:metrics-spring:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- test.local.common:web-utilities:jar:10.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- test.local.common.security:client:jar:11.10.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- test.local.common:xml:jar:12.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

Can any one establish where these dependencies may be coming from?

POM FILE

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.local.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic-zip</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.local.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>func</artifactId>
            <version>16.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-full</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.local.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.local.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-local-common</artifactId>
            <version>16.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.local.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-local-logging</artifactId>
            <version>16.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>cxf-common-utilities</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>test.local.common</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
                    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xmldsig</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.local.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-rest</artifactId>
            <version>16.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jug</groupId>
            <artifactId>jug</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-osgi</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.local.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.local.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.local.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>app</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20080701</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.local</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-local-sms-model</artifactId>
            <version>12.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.local.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webservices</artifactId>
            <version>10.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        </dependencies>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you let me see the pom.xml please? thanks

Comment: Added pom to original post

Comment: Have you a parent declared maybe?

Comment: Yes but same parent as other projects and these dependencies are not present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you haven't included all the output from `mvn dependency:tree`, so it's hard for us to see which dependency transitively dragged in the dependencies you are interested in.

If you think the output is too large for the post, you can filter out unwanted dependencies with

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework:*
```

This should give you the answer in about 5 seconds.

Comment: Brilliant that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can find out that easily using the Dependency Hierarchy or search for them in the effective POM, double click your POM file and go to these tabs as the image below[image]

Comment: I am using intelliJ. I searched in effective pom but cannot find these dependencies

Comment: They won't be in the effective POM. Only by resolving the dependency tree will you find out which dependency is bringing in the others.